# Breezejs, crossdomain

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have a minor...or maybe major.. problem regarding breezejs..
My current setup is that I have two projects.. one web-api project that hosts the breeze-api.. and another project which hosts the client-application thats supposed to consume the api..
This will give me two different ports which the api and the client runs on..

So my question is... is there any way to get breeze to work on cross-domains?.. or is breeze only built to be used inside its own domain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem going cross domain.

Ok there is a problem but it is NOT a Breeze problem. You are wrestling with the browser's "[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" that plagues us all.

You can circumvent it. Only question is how you want to go about it. And THAT question begins with "what browsers will you be supporting."  If IE10+ and latest Chrome and FF, you should go [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If older browsers and Opera ... you'll have to fight the [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) battles.

Please advise.

Nudge: Guess which one I prefer? There is already a CORS sample in Breeze ... it's [the Todo sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo) which you get with [the downloads](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download). It's not documented yet but it's in there waiting for you.

Comment: Ok great :).. I managed to get the CORS version to work, thanks :)
But how would this be done if my client has a requirement of IE7 and above for example?.. I guess this would require JSONP.. but how would I implement that?..could you point me in the right direction please :)

Comment: JSONP is harder. It requires more work on the server too because all of your endpoints have to understand JSONP and, AFAIK, there isn't a standard way to request CUD operations in JSONP.  We'll have examples ... eventually ... but it's not a priority right now to be honest.  As I said, this is a browser issue, not a Breeze issue. You can learn how to set up the server API elsewhere and then come to us when you're ready to consume it in Breeze. Sorry. Best I can offer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The Ward'd solution is very correct, am just adding a more direct solution.

Now do this install the package.

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

then add this to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Change "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to your other site * is a security risk as it allows all am using it for development

Then add this altribrute to the resource yo wish to be accesible

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Again change the origin here too remember no backslash at the end of the url.

Comment: What error are you getting? Check if you are not enabling them twice..  If you have owin libraries you might need a different approach.

Comment: I don't get any error. I just get 0 entities. I didn't enabled it twice (had it and fixed it). I tried web api and owin libraries with the same result.

Comment: Are you sure? How can you tell that the issue is with cross origns then?

Comment: I do get the entities from the same host

Comment: Open the browser console or developer tools an look at network traffic you might find the error there... It may just be a response code that will help you solve the issue

Comment: I recognized that it works for some queries. Seems that it doesn't work with requests with parameters. A Breeze bug?

Comment: It had to do with my authentication, my failure. thanks